# scroll not working in cordova application

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am developing a Cordova based application for iOS and Android.

In my application, I have a `<div>` which contains various buttons created dynamically using a `for loop`.

The problem arises when the number of buttons are greater than what can be displayed on the screen at one time. Surprisingly, scrolling does not work at all when you try with one finger, but works fine when you try with two. Even then, its not that smooth. I am not using any third party library for scrolling and I am not sure whether I am inclined to do so.

My code:

```
for(i=0;i<rows;i++){
    $("#main").append('<button>'); 
}
```

I tried putting the for loop inside a div and setting the **overflow** property as **scroll**, but it did not work.

What can I do to resolve the issue?

Comment: Have you tried `#main { overflow: auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; }` ?

Comment: did not work. am getting the same issue

Comment: Which platform(s) and version(s) is it not working for? Since Cordova is just a basic native application making use of the native webview, this issue needs to be treated like a mobile web issue. You have to consider the standards of the webviews being used in the implementation. I know that the code above works in most recent versions of iOS and 4.2+ for Android. If you are using older versions you should consider the `iScroll` JS library for scrolling.

Comment: i am trying it out on a nexus 4 right now for android and an iPhone 4s(iOS 7.1)

Comment: i am going along with iScroll for the requirement. thanks..:)